# Fields are not adding to the schema, Fields are not showing in POSTMAN even after defining in the req body

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

My MongoDB schema has fields, and i am defining those fields, but in postman body when pass the field value it doesn't show up in response:-

[This is the response i am getting  // image of the response] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzPRc.png)`

I have defined fields in the Schema but when i try to add fields afterwards in the schema it doesn't get attached and doesn't shows in POSTMAN response, but when I set its default value, then shows in the POSTMAN.

for ex- I added passwordChangedAt field, and on the sign up url in POSTMAN, i set its value in the req.body, but it doesn't show in POSTMAN response.

similarly i added role field and set its value to admin, but it doesn't show up in the POSTMAN response.

I am new to MongoDB and Mongoose, and working on a project, and i have tried everything but not able figure out thee problem.

---

**userModel JS**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
// name, email, photo, password, passwordConfirm

// const validateEmail = function(email) {
//   // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
//   const re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
//   return re.test(email);
// };

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have a name'],
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [40, 'A user name must have less or equal than 40 characters'],
    minlrngth: [1, 'A user name must have more than 1 characters']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must enter the email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please fill a valid email']
  },
  photo: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'admin'
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must set his password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      // this only works on CREATE and SAVE!!!
      validator: function(el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message:
        'Passwords are not identical. So Please enter the same password as above'
    }
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date
});
// ------- Another Way Of Doing Password Confirmation = Expand to view --------
// userSchema
//   .virtual('passwordConfirmation')
//   .get(function() {
//     return this.passwordConfirmation;
//   })
//   .set(function(value) {
//     this.passwordConfirmation = value;
//   });
// userSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
//   if (this.password !== this.passwordConfirmation) {
//     this.invalidate('passwordConfirmation', 'Enter the same password !');
//   }
//   next();
// });

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  // Hash the password with cost of 12
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  // Delete the passwordConfirm field
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function(
  candidatePassword,
  userPassword
) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
};

userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function(JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimestamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );

    console.log(this.changedTimestamp, JWTTimestamp);
    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimestamp; // 100 < 200
  }

  // False means not changed
  return false;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module. Exports = User;
```

**authController JS**

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');

const signToken = id => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
  });
};

exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
  });

  const token = signToken(newUser._id);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'Success',
    token,
    data: {
      user: newUser
    }
  });
});

exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // 1) Check if email and apssword exists
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
  }
  // 2) Check if user exists && password is correct
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }

  // 3) If every is okay, end the token to client
  const token = signToken(user._id);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    token
  });
});

exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Getting the token and check if it exists
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }

  if (!token) {
    return next(
      new AppError('You are not logged in! Please log in to get access', 401)
    );
  }

  // 2) Verfication token
  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  // 3) Check if user still exists
  const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
  if (!currentUser) {
    return next(
      new AppError(
        'The user belonging to this token, does no longer exist',
        401
      )
    );
  }
  // 4) Check if user changed password after the token was issued
  if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
    return next(
      new AppError(
        'User has changed the password! Please log in with the new password',
        400
      )
    );
  }
  // Grant Access to the protected route
  req.user = currentUser;
  next();
});

exports.restrictTo = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    // roles ['admin', 'lead-guide]
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new AppError('You do not have permission to perform this action', 403)
      );
    }

    next();
  };
};
```

Comment: you're not passing those fields when you're creating new user in `signup` method in `authController JS`. you only pass `name, email, password, passwordconfirm`